# Url rewrite for an existing website

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I hope this is not a very stupid question. I have to rewrite the url's of an existing website. I have never done that before, so I'm a little bit confused. I have allready written some rules that make a page like faq.php be accessible also by entering only faq without the .php extension, but the page fap.php it's still accessible and in the footer when I move the mouse over the faq icon the link shown in the browser is faq.php. To make the browser display faq and not faq.php do I have to change the href link in the page manually or there is another way?
For example: in this website(stackoverflow) when you move the mouse over questions, tags, users or other links, the browser displays only /questions (or the others) without .php(or whatever they used to built the website). How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want your HTML markup to use the pretty URLs you need to modify the markup. You _could_ use JavaScript to rewrite all the links on the page according to your rules, saving you having to modify your PHP code to output them without their extensions.  I'm absolutely not saying you _should_.

Comment: could, but not should means that it's not a good idea? A redirect in th .htaccess is also not a good idea? I don't know what's better in terms of SEO and time-consuming(for me)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you definitely don't want to do that. It's terrible from an SEO perspective, since content then 'lives' in 2 locations. Additioanlly, old links should be 301 redirected to new links in order to maintain any SEO rank. Also, who wants to track down javascript that's arbitrarily changing the DOM.

Comment: It's an existing website, but it's not online yet(only a small part), so I don't have to use the 301 redirect, no?

Comment: @ChrisHenry Hence why I said _absolutely not saying you should_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the status bar is what your server sends to the browser.

To remove `.php` from `faq.php` you must either

- send only `faq` (PHP) or
- replace the contents of `href` attributes on the client side (JavaScript).